# How to control eye reflection?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I've just found [following picture](http://hiddenus.deviantart.com/art/Eyes-node-set-452225762), but I don't know how to recreate this kind of crystal type reflection thing. Can anyone teach me please?

[image]

Comment: What do you exactly mean by saying "crystal type reflection"?

Comment: i posted a BG and BI image just for the heck of it.

Comment: Also look into (heh) the actual geometry of the eye: the iris and pupil are inset. This really changes the lighting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see in the picture and the [material node provided from creator](http://www.deviantart.com/art/Eyes-node-set-452225762) (which contain some errors in my opinion) the reflection is achieved by simply mixing a glossy shader and a diffuse shader.

The sharpness of the reflection is driven by the "Roughness" value of the shader:

[image]

High Roughness value

[image]

Low Roughness value

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### BI or BG

First of all, you need to choose a reflection image. (I love using city landscapes off of http://cgtextures.com/.

Then add a new texture and set the mapping to *"reflection"*.

The image is calculated in realtime, so its 100% game functional (and looks beautiful)

[image]